# Share App Service plan in different azure resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I have two web apps in different Resource Groups. I want to use a shared App Service Plan. Please guide how this can be done, When I try to use "Change Service Plan" I can not see another resource group service plan. Both Resource groups are in same region. When I try to create a App Service Plan I can not see option as a shared resource.

Comment: Resource Groups are just organizational (and security) boundaries for who can access resources, and what they can do with them. You can use Azure services that span resource groups - there is no restriction where a service is tied to other services within its own resource group. Resources can be spread across any number of resource groups.  Is there a specific issue you're having?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am trying to select service plan which is associated with other resource group. When I try to use change service plan, I can see Service Plan of same group in drop down list and I can see "create new " label but not able to see service plan of another group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to move App Service to App Service plan in another resource group.

> You can move an app to another App Service plan, as long as the source
> plan and the target plan **are in the same resource group and
> geographical region.**

Additional Info:

> Azure deploys each new App Service plan into a deployment unit,
> internally called a webspace. Each region can have many webspaces, but
> your app can only move between plans that are created in the same
> webspace. An App Service Environment is an isolated webspace, so apps
> can be moved between plans in the same App Service Environment, but
> not between plans in different App Service Environments.
>
> You can’t specify the webspace you want when creating a plan, but it’s
> possible to ensure that a plan is created in the same webspace as an
> existing plan. In brief, all plans created with the same resource
> group and region combination are deployed into the same webspace. For
> example, if you created a plan in resource group A and region B, then
> any plan you subsequently create in resource group A and region B is
> deployed into the same webspace. Note that plans can’t move webspaces
> after they’re created, so you can’t move a plan into “the same
> webspace” as another plan by moving it to another resource group.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-plan-manage#move-an-app-to-another-app-service-plan

Comment: FYI the OP isn't asking about moving between regions.

Comment: @TomaszKaniewski Yes I read that article, Thanks clarifying. It was actually confusing, People were saying Resource group are only groups and we can use them as required.

Answer (score 1):

I am too late for the show, but still - it's possible to at least CREATE an App Service with App Service Plan from another resource group (not geographical region though).

You can pick up some details from here:

https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2019/09/11/share-azure-app-service-plan-across-resource-groups/